# ConEmu and Babun does not display all console output from cli apps

Tags: windows, conemu, babun

Curious question about cli output in babun on windows. What would cause the minimal amount of output in babun vs something like cmd? I realize this question might not have a simple answer and is loaded with ignorance but it has been bugging me a while.

Running something like Mongo is the perfect example. The first is cmd and shows all output.

[image]

This is babun
[image]

Notice that there is no '>' and it stops at the MongoDB server version line. Is babun just ancient and should not be used?

Comment: The `babun` is neither a shell nor an executable. Tell us first, what do you run exactly - process tree.

Comment: So I believe it is zsh in a cygwin environment?

Comment: You believe, but can't check? It's your pc, nope? If the process tree is mintty.exe/zsh.exe that means that mongo will not work properly in the POSIX terminal, it needs full featured WinAPI terminal.